# Android NDK Plugin in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

On June 28, 2012

Android releases the new version of SDK, the r20

also the new ADT Eclipse plugin v20. However I was surprised because they've included the NDK Plugin.

**The question is, how to use their new NDK Plugin?** I'm expecting the development in native side is easier because of the NDK Plugin.

Comment: Remember to updated Eclipse, the updated things, and download the Android 4.1 Jelly Bean (API 16) SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [answer](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) in 
[Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com)